# UI Testing Failure: Multiple Matches Found Error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, xcode-ui-testing

When trying to perform UI `Testing` using `XCode`. I have `UITableView` with multiple matches of same type. Is there anyway I can tap() on any cell of same type randomly without providing `elementBoundByIndex(0)` to select a specific one.

```
let firstButton = accordianButtonsQuery.elementBoundByIndex(0)
firstButton.tap()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a random index between 0 and the `count` of elements matching the query, and use that with `elementBoundByIndex`, but you can't just have the tap execute on a random element.

Gestures require a specific element to target. This should prompt you to remove randomness from your tests to make them deterministic and therefore predictable. Introducing randomness into a test makes it unpredictable, difficult to debug, and possibly fragile/flaky.